# How to pass action to Laravel 8 routes?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-8

I was using following Route declaration to pass `language` action to the routes.

```
Route::get('/de', ['uses' => 'PageController@showHomepage', 'language' => 'de']);
```

And in controller, I was able to get this value like this:

```
$action = $request->route()->getAction();
// $action['language'] gives the given value here..
```

But with callable syntax, I couldn't find how can I do the same thing. When using the following type of route definition:

```
Route::get('/', [PageController::class, 'showHomepage']);
```

How can I pass the `language` to new declaration? Is that a way to pass arguments to callable in Route::get() ?

Something like this

```
Route::get('/', ([PageController::class, 'showHomepage'],'languagecode_parameter_here'));
```

Thank you very much.

PS: If you are asking why do I need such custom parameter, here is more details about the need: https://github.com/laravel/framework/discussions/44839

Comment: Why not define it to your controller ? `public function index($language = 'de') {...}`

Comment: What are you trying to achieve? You can pass the language via request variable

Comment: Unfortunately I cannot pass it with request variable as it needs to be defined constantly. So somehow I need to pass constant values to controller, it was possible before but couldn't find a way with new definitions. I didn't define it on controller because couldn't find a way to pass this value. (It can be "de" or some other language code)

Comment: What I need is, something like Route::get('/', [PageController::class, 'showHomepage'])->where('language', 'en'); but without adding {language} to the URL part.

Comment: Here is more details about the need: https://github.com/laravel/framework/discussions/44839

Comment: Just asking: Why do you need that in your routes? How do you determine what lang is used on what route? Is there some kind of url-indication (like, having a subdomain with <lang>.example.com to get the lang?). Have read the github link, still questions to understand the issue.

Comment: @Paladin it's kind of old project and uses paths on root (/someurl) for English for example, but also uses /langcode/someotherurl for other languages. Because of that I cannot use [langcode]/someurl format because there are some urls like /artist/songname for example and "artist" here is interfering with  [langcode]/someurl format. And also there are different formats for same content like /de/artist/songname-somegermantexthere. So I need to pass language to some controllers. I did it with route names, not the best practice but at least a way to do it.

Answer (score 1):

Reading your last comment, I would suggest you to create a middleware to set the language. You can call your route with the middleware that is actually "right" for it (or group the routes with that middleware). This way, your project is more future-orientated and organized.

See the docs https://laravel.com/docs/master/middleware

Comment: I used route names as a workaround but your suggestion is also great. Thank you!

Answer (score -2):

You can’t.

And this is not appropirate way to localize your routes in laravel.

If you want to set localization for your laravarl application there is a package fir that and the name of pakcage in github is mcamara/laravel-localization it is one of the best localization packages.

[Package github link](https://github.com/mcamara/laravel-localization)

Comment: It's not just about localization. There are other scenarios which needs that too and it was possible with string syntax routes. Here is more details about the need: https://github.com/laravel/framework/discussions/44839